# Find position in array for unknown string

Tags: c#, arrays, string, linq, lambda

I'm searching for a part of a string in an array, but I don't know what contains that part of the string.
After I , but I need the position of this string also.
I have the following code:

```
   string Cuvant = "+NATURAL,,";

   string[] prefixes = { "/", "+", ",", "’’", "“", "”", ",," };
    string str = "";

    if (prefixes.Any(prefix => Cuvant.StartsWith(prefix)))
    {
      // Strip the first character from string
      str = Cuvant.Substring(1);

      // Search the end of string in prefixes
      if (prefixes.Any(prefix => str.EndsWith(prefix)))
      {
        // Strip the last character from string
        // here I need to know if the end found in prefixes is more than a character
        str = str.Substring(0, str.Length -1);
       }
    }
```

I opted to not use if... else because the prefixes, in the future, can have more words that it has now.

Comment: For this "+NATURAL,," string you expect as result "NATURAL"?

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. Can you please describe what you are trying to achieve as I believe there is a better way. To answer what I think you're asking for, take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem, you are looking for something that will clean your string by removing invalid characters at the beginning and at the end.

Then just use [`Trim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
string cuvant = "+NATURAL,,";

char[] prefixes = { '/', '+', ',', '’', '“', '”', ',' };

cuvant = cuvant.Trim(prefixes);
```

Note that prfixes array become an array of `char` type.

Comment: thanks, this is what I was searching for. I forgot about the Trim(char[]).